# What is the difference between Display.getRotation() and Display.getOrientation() apart from the fact that Display.getOrientation() is deprecated?

Tags: android, screen, orientation

What is the difference between Display.getRotation() and Display.getOrientation() apart from the fact that it Display.getOrientation() is deprecated?

Do both return an `int` equal to one of Surface.ROTATION_0, Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, Surface.ROTATION_270?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

getRotation() just calls the deprecated method getOrientation(), check the [source code of class Display](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-sdk-4.0.3_r1/core/java/android/view/Display.java#L249). So it seems to have been deprecated merely for a better name.

Comment: FYI, the link is now broken.

Comment: Sorry, it is working.  Maybe the site was momentarily down, and I assumed the link was broken.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods are exactly the same, getRotation() simply calls getOrientation(). For this reason, I am using getOrientation() in my app in order to add support for lower Android levels. I see no reason to limit my ability to distribute my app simply so it can have a different method name. Thus, I completely agree with jap1968.

Answer (score 0):

The answer just tells the same as the Android documentation. Many people has devices whose manufacturers do not update. I find nonsense to make an application just for users having modern devices, when the main functionality of the application does not require anything not present even (in my case) in API v1.

Answer (score -3):

From Android Developer Site [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html):

> public int getOrientation ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 This method is
>   deprecated. use getRotation()
>
> Returns
>
> orientation of this display.
>
> ---
>
> public int getRotation ()
>
> Since: API Level 8 Returns the
>   rotation of the screen from its
>   "natural" orientation. The returned
>   value may be Surface.ROTATION_0 (no
>   rotation), Surface.ROTATION_90,
>   Surface.ROTATION_180, or
>   Surface.ROTATION_270. For example, if
>   a device has a naturally tall screen,
>   and the user has turned it on its side
>   to go into a landscape orientation,
>   the value returned here may be either
>   Surface.ROTATION_90 or
>   Surface.ROTATION_270 depending on the
>   direction it was turned. The angle is
>   the rotation of the drawn graphics on
>   the screen, which is the opposite
>   direction of the physical rotation of
>   the device. For example, if the device
>   is rotated 90 degrees
>   counter-clockwise, to compensate
>   rendering will be rotated by 90
>   degrees clockwise and thus the
>   returned value here will be
>   Surface.ROTATION_90.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan but this is just what it says in the javadoc; I've read this before.  It doesn't say weather or not they are equivalent and getOrientation is simply being deprecated for a better name or if it is there is a different.

Comment: @Gallal, I assume it is the same or else they would have warned in the docs. In either case, what are you trying to achieve, are you trying to port a part of code still using the deprecated method? Also, look at [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg124496.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, if there's a deprecation notice and the only documentation says "use thisMethod() instead", then it's a pretty safe bet that the only change is the method name (in some cases, a signature change as well).  However, be mindful of the API level where the non-deprecated method was introduced.  If you intend to support Android 1.5 - 3.1+, then you can't rely on `getRotation()`, because that won't exist in SDK levels < 8.  If you're already targeting SDK-8 and above only, then you should use `getRotation()` instead.